# Is there a way to add a font awesome icon in a printf before the value?

Tags: php, html, font-awesome

I'm struggling to insert a font awesome icon before the value in a `printf`.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="numerical-rating" data-rating="<?php $rating_value = esc_attr(round($rating,1)); printf("%0.1f",$rating_value); ?>">
```

Where should I place it to display it right before the value?

Comment: Wherever your little heart desires. Note that font-awesome has nothing to do with PHP, it's purely a HTML/CSS image. Look at the source in the browser so you can see how the code will be parsed, then decide where to put the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the class directly in the class-list as it will add a `:before` element to your wrapper:

```
<div class="fas fa-home numerical-rating" data-rating="<?php $rating_value = esc_attr(round($rating,1)); printf("%0.1f",$rating_value); ?>"></div>
```

Or place an icon wherever you need it:

```
<div><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Any Text</div>
```

I is used for italic, but it's common to use it for icons aswell.